# Unable to print languages other than English in System.windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Tags: c#, encoding, browser

I am trying to use `System.windows.Forms.WebBrowser` to display a content in the languages **other than English**, but the resulting encoding is incorrect. What should I do to display for example Russian?

I am downloading and displaying a string as following:

```
 System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
 webBrsr.DocumentText = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: And is the downloaded content actually _in_ Russian?

Comment: DocumentText is a string, utf16 in .NET.  It can't have an encoding problem.  WebBrowser is Internet Explorer, it doesn't have any trouble with Russian either.  Your problem is on the right side of the =

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#:". We use tags for that purpose on [SO].

Comment: @hans-passant  "Your problem is on the right side of the =". Which is what problem? Internet Explorer does show the same site in Russian.

Comment: Post the url that reproduces this problem if you need help finding out why DownloadString gets the encoding wrong.  Talking to the site owner is your best bet.

Comment: @hans-passant Thanks a lot for your reply. I do not think that it is related to a particular site. Browser displays incorrectly any site in a language other than English. I can give you as an example Google's news site in Russian: http://news.google.com/news?edchanged=1&ned=ru_ru

Comment: @mr-disappointment Yes, the content is in Russian. Russian news from Google for example (the link is above).

Comment: Add wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 to solve the problem.  This is not a universal solution, different web sites may use different encodings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `WebClient` and how it is interpreting the string encoding. One solution is to download the data as raw bytes and parse it out manually:

```
Bytes[] bytes = wc.DownloadData("http://news.google.com/news?edchanged=1&ned=ru_ru");
//You should really inspect the headers from the response to determine the exact encoding to use,
//    this example just assumes UTF-8 which might work in most scenarios
String t = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
webBrsr.DocumentText = t;
```

Comment: Great! I am fine with just UTF-8. I have tried something like the code bellow with no luck, but now all works fine with your solution. Thanks a lot Chris! 
    // THIS CODE IS WRONG. 
    byte[] myDataBuffer = wc.DownloadData(url); 
    webBrsr.DocumentText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myDataBuffer);

Comment: @Gen, great to hear. For what its worth, `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` isn't really what most people think it is. I personally think it should be removed or at least renamed to `UTF16LE` or something similar.